# how to hit a controller on another IP using mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, httpwebrequest

I am very new here with MVC.

I want to call a method using httpwebrequest that exist on another server.

Suppose there are two server with IP 10.100.248.103  and 10.100.248.104

Both method given below exist on both server.

```
public bool updateAllServer()
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://10.100.248.104/VirtaulDirectoryPath/UpdateSharedVars/updateME");
        request.ContentType= "application/json";
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        this.Status = ((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription;
        return true;
    }

public bool updateMe()
    {
        allVariables.SetAll();
        return true;
    }
```

I am on server 10.100.248.103, and hit the updateAllServer() that will do a call UpdateMe method on server 104.

"http://10.100.248.104/VirtaulDirectoryPath/UpdateSharedVars/updateME"

In simple words , I want to Hit UpdateMe method that exist on 10.100.248.104 from server 10.100.248.103.
I am not sure how to achieve this functionality.Please help
I am using MVC4.